# Is it possible to add questions to my favourites?

Tags: support, bookmarks

I'm a new Stack Overflow user and don't see how to add question to my favourites.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the star beneath the score, left of the question.

Since you're new, you probably didn't know this yet, but questions about programming belong on Stackoverflow, but questions about Stackoverflow belong on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Press the star button on the left hand side under the up/down buttons where you question is!